# wp-cli silently fails with 255 when running wp core install

Tags: wp-cli

Working within a Docker container (circleci/php:latest) and I'm struggling with wp-cli a bit. When I attempt to run `wp core install` I get a silent failure with 255 exit code. I enabled --debug hoping to get some more information but unfortunately all I can see is that it stops after reading wp-config.php.

```
circleci@142b5627c098:~/wordpress$ wp core install --url=example.com --title="Example" --admin_user=admin --admin_email=admin@example.com --skip-email --debug
Debug (bootstrap): Fallback autoloader paths: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/autoload.php (0.01s)
Debug (bootstrap): Loading detected autoloader: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/autoload.php (0.011s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache (0.015s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: transient (0.017s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: comment (0.019s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in comment Namespace (0.02s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: menu (0.021s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: item in menu Namespace (0.022s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: location in menu Namespace (0.022s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: network meta (0.023s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: option (0.024s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: post (0.026s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in post Namespace (0.026s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term in post Namespace (0.027s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: post-type (0.028s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: site (0.03s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in site Namespace (0.031s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: option in site Namespace (0.032s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: taxonomy (0.033s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term (0.034s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in term Namespace (0.035s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: user (0.037s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in user Namespace (0.038s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: session in user Namespace (0.039s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: term in user Namespace (0.04s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: network (0.04s)
Debug (hooks): Processing hook "after_add_command:network" with 1 callbacks (0.04s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:network": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.04s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: meta in network Namespace (0.041s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: db (0.044s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: plugin (0.048s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: theme (0.05s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: mod in theme Namespace (0.051s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: scaffold (0.053s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core (0.053s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: verify-checksums in core Namespace (0.054s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: verify-checksums in plugin Namespace (0.055s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: export (0.056s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: config (0.058s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core (0.06s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: eval (0.061s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: eval-file (0.061s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: import (0.062s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: media (0.063s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: package (0.065s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cron (0.066s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: event in cron Namespace (0.067s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: schedule in cron Namespace (0.067s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: embed (0.068s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: fetch in embed Namespace (0.068s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: provider in embed Namespace (0.069s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: handler in embed Namespace (0.069s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache in embed Namespace (0.07s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: i18n (0.07s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: make-pot in i18n Namespace (0.071s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: make-json in i18n Namespace (0.072s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language core (0.073s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language plugin (0.073s)
Debug (commands): Deferring command: language theme (0.074s)
Debug (hooks): Immediately invoking on passed hook "after_add_command:site": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/language-command/language-command.php at line 39 (0.074s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: switch-language in site Namespace (0.074s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: language (0.074s)
Debug (hooks): Processing hook "after_add_command:language" with 3 callbacks (0.074s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.074s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: core in language Namespace (0.075s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.075s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: plugin in language Namespace (0.076s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "after_add_command:language": Closure in file phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/class-wp-cli.php at line 634 (0.076s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: theme in language Namespace (0.076s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: maintenance-mode (0.077s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: rewrite (0.078s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: rewrite (0.078s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cap (0.079s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: role (0.08s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: search-replace (0.082s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: server (0.082s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: shell (0.083s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: super-admin (0.083s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: widget (0.085s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: sidebar (0.085s)
Debug (bootstrap): Adding framework command: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/commands/cli.php (0.085s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cli (0.087s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: cache in cli Namespace (0.088s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: alias in cli Namespace (0.088s)
Debug (bootstrap): Adding framework command: phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/commands/help.php (0.088s)
Debug (commands): Adding command: help (0.089s)
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.089s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.089s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /usr/local/bin/wp core install --url=example.com --title="Example" --admin_user=admin --admin_email=admin@example.com --skip-email --debug (0.09s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /home/circleci/wordpress/ (0.09s)
Debug (bootstrap): Set URL: example.com (0.09s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.09s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /home/circleci/wordpress/wp-config.php (0.09s)
circleci@142b5627c098:~/wordpress$
```

I've tried regenerating wp-config using `wp config create` with just the bare minimum and visually inspected and it seems fine but no change.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit in which environment you are doing this (Docker), and if you can install the site from the browser? Can you please also paste your `wp config create` command? What does `wp config list` return you? Can you access `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD` from the command line?

Comment: In my config.yml I have:
`wp config create --dbhost=127.0.0.1 --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=root --path=wordpress/`
And it retuns `Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.` when I check the log.

But I am also testing on a VM of my own with the same container but my setup is unfortunately slightly different so my command is:
`wp config create --dbhost=127.0.0.1 --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=root --path=wordpress/`

Local I tried with no password as well but I though it may have been causing a problem. I have no issues using the mysql client to connect.

Comment: And when you use the same container combination as in the sample repo from my answer? Then it should work. What does your `.circleci/config.yml` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing some php extensions that wp-cli and/or WordPress needed but there is no error output stating as much. I'm guessing it was specifically the missing mysqli extension.

I used a [WP-CLI command](https://github.com/johnbillion/ext) to test the base container for missing extensions and now I have `sudo docker-php-ext-install gd sockets mysqli exif` in my config.yml.

Thanks to @leymannx for linking his own repo that got me onto the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Now I just saw, that you are in a CircleCI container! I heavily rely on CircleCI containers for WordPress development. And I remember I once had the same problem. It's because your host needs to be specified as `127.0.0.1` with `--dbhost` like this:

```
$ wp config create --dbname=circle_test --dbuser=root --dbpass="" --dbhost=127.0.0.1
```

---

I also have a working sample repo live which may help you further: https://github.com/leymannx/wordpress-circleci-behat. Maybe you can check your `.circleci/config.yml` against the one from this repo to find the culprit.

Comment: So it wasn't a problem with the database host config but your repo did help me out. I was missing some php extensions that wp-cli and/or WordPress needed but there is no error output stating as much. I'm guessing it was specifically the missing mysqli extension.

I used a [WP-CLI command](https://github.com/johnbillion/ext) to test the base container for missing extensions and now I have `sudo docker-php-ext-install gd sockets mysqli exif` in my config.yml.